# Higher IF can cause clock jitters?

Tags: spectrum-analyzer, mixer

I was reading about Intermediate Frequency [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_frequency), and it says that if the IF is too high, it can cause clock jitters.  This is the first time I hear about this, and I cannot find any references that would explain this.  Does anyone know why this happens? -- or alternatively, where I can find more information about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick read over the article, it seems to me it is poorly written, I suspect by someone who might have outdated information.

While I would say that the phase noise performance decreases with increasing frequency, it seems a bit phrase that as 'the main reason' for limiting IF frequency.

The reason clocks tend to get worse with increasing frequency is because the phase noise is actually related to the Q-factor of the oscillator. A higher q-factor requires a lower amount of loss in the oscillator tank (both because this means we need less gain, which means the gain-block will add less noise, and inherently because the loss of an oscillator tank means it has noise, which in turn means phase noise).

Physics is kinda out to get us when we move to higher frequencies. Three factors make our life harder: 
First, the gain a transistor can deliver decreases with frequency. At some point, this becomes 0 dB (or the transistor really doesn't add to the signal power). Depending on if we talk about current or power gain, this point is called the \$f_t\$ or \$f_{max}\$ of that transistor.

Second, metals become less good at conduction. Or at least so it would seem- you need to actually go to much, much higher frequencies than found in day-to-day applications to see this. What we do see, is the skin effect. At higher frequencies, skin-effect pushes current to the surface, which reduces the actual metal carrying the current (=higher resistance) and also makes us more sensitive to surface roughness.

Third: in general, dielectric become more lossy at higher frequencies, and this two gives us more loss.

All this adds up to give us in the end, more phase noise.

Oh, and next to that: If you just multiply the frequency of a signal, you also multiply the amount of phase noise. It could be they are also referring to this.

Comment: What do you mean by "dielectric become more lossy at higher frequencies"? -- it seems you're missing something, since dielectric is an adjective...

Comment: I meant Dielectrics, the plural of Dielectric, or "a medium or substance with a dielectric property; an insulator."

Answer (score 0):

I feel its a roundabout description, If you make the frequency too high, the only way to produce that frequency is via a Phase lock loop, the higher the multiplication of the original frequency, the higher the jitter

This is partly due to the PLL being limited to having worse jitter than the clock that it is derived from, and the effect of this jitter is multiplied with the frequency,

low jitter clock sources get unreasonably expensive very quickly, e.g. rubidium GSM modules,

Comment: Rubidium (or I think any other atomic/molecular clock) is not generally a low-jitter clock source. Usually they are used with a low-jitter source like a oven-controlled crystal oscillator to provide a low-jitter clock.

Comment: Also, the article talks about *downmixing* the original frequency.  So PLL would not be used in either case.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. For fixed time jitter, the phase noise will linearly increase with increases in clock frequency because the clock period becomes smaller while the time uncertainly remains the same.

In a phase-locked frequency-multiplier, if loop adds ZERO time jitter, the PLL merely copies the Reference time jitter to be the output time jitter. In using a 100MHz Reference to generate a 5,000MHz ADC sampling clock, the ratio of clock_period/jitter drops by 50:1, and your phasenoise increases by 50X (power? or voltage? I forget), either 17dB or 34dB.

Some people generate low-phasenoise high frequency tones (such as needed for ADC sampling or for LocalOscillator injection into Mixers) using high-purity dielectric-disc-in-cavity, which is basically a extreme-Q bandpass_filter used as an oscillator.

Suppose you want total integrated jitter to be 1e-18 seconds. This is 1 attoSecond. How to get there?

Given TimeJitter = Vnoise/Slewrate, you need (one possible combination)

Vnoise of 1 nanoVoltRMS and SlewRate of 1 Billion volts per second.

Given Vnoise of 62 ohm resistor is 1.00 nanoVolts/rtHz RMS, then in 10GHz bandwidth you'll have 1nV * sqrt(10,000,000,000) = 1nV * 100,000 = 100 microVolts RMS noise.

You can achieve 1 volt/10 picoseconds slewrates (I think you can) but need to burn power to reach the 62_ohm noise level.

What does this provide us, so far as time jitter?

Tj = Vn/SR = 100uV/100 Billion volts per second = u / Billion = 1e-15 seconds

This is 1 femto seconds. Real hard to get to that point. Thus an attoSecond requires massive narrow-band filtering.

==========================

Regarding upmixing and downmixing: the paragraph refering to "mixing" is equally valid for both cases. The Local Oscillator phasenoise will be wrapped around each and every tone that enters the RF port.

Now for terms: consider a sinusoidal LO energy source: the slewrate is

d(Amplitude * sin(2 * pi * frequency)/dTime

or

(Amplitude *2 * pi * Frequency) * cosine (2 * pi *  frequency)

For 100MHz reference frequency with +- 10 volts amplitude, the SlewRate is

(10) volts * (2 * pi * 100MHZ) radians/second = 6,280 Million volts/second

We easily compute the SlewRate for a SQUARE WAVE (with finite rise and fall times), as you might imagine.

And finally, RMS for a sin is 1.414 * the Peak amplitude.

However, for random noise with the well-accepted bell-curve Gaussian distribution, the "RMS" merely tells us the "1_sigma" value, from which we can predict 2_sigma or 3.5 sigma, or 6.2sigma likelihood (which is the 1ppm tail).

Comment: It's *power*, not voltage.  Also, this answer concerns upmixing, whereas the article in question talks about downmixing.  However, interesting information nonetheless.  Also: what is *Slewrate*?  What is RMS?  Sorry, I haven't encountered these terms in downmixing.